# R function for date range in ggplot

Tags: r, date, ggplot2

I am currently trying to produce graphs for a difference in difference study using r. I want to have a centered date on the axis, and I would like to make a function that specifes how wide the window should be around that date. For example, if the input was 2, there would be data displayed for 2 days before the central date and 2 days after the central date. What is the best way to do this using ggplot?

I can not think of the best method for doing this, so any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You could make a simple wrapper around `scale_x_date`:

```r
library(ggplot2)

scale_x_datearound <- function(date, daysaround, ...) {
  scale_x_date(limits = as.Date(date) + c(-daysaround, daysaround), ...)
}
```

So, suppose we have a plot like this:

```r
df <- data.frame(x = seq(as.Date("2023-03-09"), by = "day", len = 10), y = 1:10)

p <- ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) + geom_line() + geom_point()

p
```

[image]

We can center it on 12th March with 2 days on either side like this:

```r
p + scale_x_datearound("2023-03-12", daysaround = 2)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-03-09 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: This is helpful thank you. If I wanted to change it to weeks instead of days, would that be a possibility?

Comment: Yes. Change the name of daysaround to weeksaround and use `as.Date(date) + 7 * c(-weeksaround, weeksaround)a inside the function (you are simply multiplying by 7 to turn days into weeks)